# Handling JSON posts in Yesod

Tags: json, haskell, post, yesod

An AngularJS client is sending a JSON post to a Yesod server to update a person record. The post can contain the following fields each of which is optional - the client can send any subset of these:

- firstName
- lastName
- ...
- active

To limit the discussion a bit lets assume the client, at the moment, only wants to toggle activity, so it will only send the active value (it specifically wants to keep the rest intact) and the message will be:

```
{
  active: 0
}
```

On the server now, we know the id of the person from the URL (eg. /api/v1.0/person/1) but the client does not send a complete Person entity, so the usual:

```
person <- requireJsonBody :: Handler Person
_ <- runDB $ update personId ...
```

will not work here. It would seem a more flexible approach is needed. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
mapToUpdate :: PersonInfo -> [Update PersonInfo]
```

where PersonInfo is an instance of `FromJSON` and is defined to match Person but has all the fields of type `Maybe a`. However, that seems totally contrary to DRY.

So to wrap this up: how would one handle such a use case in Yesod nicely going back and assuming again the client can send any subset of a Person's fields?

You could imagine even more horrifying scenarios. For example one JSON post needing to be mapped to an update of multiple database entities (api entities do not have to map 1:1 to database entities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this, but here's a theoretical approach:

1. Grab the current value from the database
2. Serialize that value to an aeson `Value` by calling `toJSON`
3. Write some kind of "update" algorithm that merges two `Value`s together, e.g. `mergeValues :: Value -> Value -> Value`
4. Merge the original entity with the value uploaded by the user
5. Try to parse the resulting value with `parseJSON`
6. If it succeeds, use `replace` to put it back into the database

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! I might end up going with this but it's still far from ideal. A lot of unnecessary processing not to mention fetching the whole entity from the db - a whole another query. What I would really want is a way to translate the json stuff to a persistent update statement.

Comment: While it's possible to derive something like that automatically using Template Haskell or GHC Generics, that code hasn't been written yet. You may be able to take a crack at writing some such code, which would then give you full flexibility to implement this exactly as you want.

Comment: If you end up using this approach, watch out for race conditions where request A and B pull the value from the database at the same time, then request A updates one property and request B updates a different one. Since the requests are replacing the full record, request B could overwrite A's changes, even if they were updating separate fields.